# how to remove unused elements from xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

So i am new to xslt, and i have looked online but I just got confused. I just removed the Location setting now I want to remove Location element in XML file:

and in my xslt file I have this transformation to modify XML file

```
      <xsl:when test="@name = 'Location'">
        <xsl:call-template name="ConvertElement">
          <xsl:with-param name="element" select="." />
          <xsl:with-param name="newElement" select="../Location" />
          <xsl:with-param name="newElementName" select="'Location'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
```

what would be xslt transformation to remove that Location element XML file?

Comment: Please share the source xml

Comment: on xml file i have   <Location>NewYork</Location>

Comment: XSLT - 
While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Comment: yeah i should have added all the steps

Comment: It is never late. Please edit your question, and provide ##1-4.

Comment: the solution provided by Mads worked, just needed to change my xpath, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see more of your XSLT, to be able to provide a more specific and correct answer.

A general answer for a means of removing a given element, when using an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) is to add an empty template that matches the element(s) that you want removed. Then, when the template matches that element, it won't produce any output or do any further processing of that element's nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Location"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this worked, just needed to change my xpath, thanks